# How to test if java has support for tls v1.2 support. Sample test

Tags: java, linux, ssl, tls1.2, java-security

I am using a linux based device where openssl tool is present. 
So basically I verified that my device supports tls v1.2 by executing below command:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -tls1_2
```

and got below output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

and it is verified that device has a support for tls.

I need the same activity for java where a sample application will decide if the current version of java does support for tls1.2.

Please feel free to update and ask anything! Thanks.

Comment: enable network debug in java(-Djavax.net.debug=all) and you can find out tls version in debug message

Comment: If you want to enforce java to use tls 1.2 you can set the parameter -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2